# Spring cloud stream messaging system(RabbitMQ) implementation using Rest Controller(Restful API)

Tags: spring, stream, cloud

From past few days i'm trying to implement the Spring cloud stream messaging system using RestController, but it is not happening through the current implementation.

### For this sample code i'm going to add RestController

```
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(TimeSourceOptionsMetadata.class)

public class TimeSource {

    @Autowired
    private TimeSourceOptionsMetadata options;
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = Source.OUTPUT)
    public String timerMessageSource() {
        return new SimpleDateFormat(this.options.getFormat()).format(new Date());
    }
}
```

---

But the `@InboundChannelAdapter` cannot accept any parameters from `RequestMapping` Get Method URL.At the end what i need is to add message to the broker using Restful API Get method from api call. which is the best way to do it?, I couldn't figure out any best process from internet.

Answer (score 0):

spring cloud team already provided a source application that listens for HTTP requests and emits the body as a message payload. If the Content-Type matches text/* or application/json, the payload will be a String, otherwise the payload will be a byte array.
[github link](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/http)

You can go with this or if you want to write it yourself, you can do it like below:

```
@RestController
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class RestSource {

    @Autowired
    private Source channels;

    @RequestMapping(path = "/", method = POST, consumes = {"application/json" })
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
    public void handleRequest(@RequestBody String body, @RequestHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE) Object contentType) {
        sendMessage(body, contentType);
    }

    private void sendMessage(Object body, Object contentType) {
        channels.output().send(MessageBuilder.createMessage(body,
                new MessageHeaders(Collections.singletonMap(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, contentType))));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for your response.It really helped me a lot. The following url gives complete source and sink development using spring integration with spring cloud=> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HQ00E60kB6c